# IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate 2020.1.2 - Tomcat 8.5.55 - war file not in webapps dir

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea

Am using IntellIJ IDEA Ultimate Edition 2020.1.2 and Tomcat 8.5.55 on macOS Catalina 10.15.5

Have setup a run configuration inside IntelliJ for Tomcat.

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Am able to run Tomcat via IntelliJ IDEA and everything works (am able to run tomcat and see my webapp inside Google Chrome & see catalina.out via IntelliJ) but when I go to the webapps dir, I don't see the unpacked war file anywhere?

```
cd $CATALINA_HOME/webapps
```

---

```
ls
```

---

Directory listing:

```
ROOT        docs        examples    host-manager    manager
```

---

Question(s):

1. How can I setup / edit my Tomcat local run configuration to move the war file (whether exploded or not) inside `$CATALINA_HOME/webapps`?
2. Where is this IntelliJ generated war file located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Configure the [artifact output path](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html) to be under `webapps` directory.
2. In the artifact output directory.

Normally there is no need to change it, IntelliJ IDEA instructs Tomcat to deploy from the configured artifact output location.

Comment: That worked... You also have to append the app's name inside webapps e.g. ```$CATALINA_HOME/webapps/ams``` - (otherwise, it will unpack inside ```webapps```).